# Is it possible to use .NET application in MatLab?

Tags: c#, web-services, matlab

I feel at home in C# and I'll design a console application that will fetch some data from a web service. I'd like to allow a group of scientists to use the data in MatLab. One way to achieve that is to store it in a file on the HDD and then load the contents of it into MatLab.

That got me thinking, though. **Is it possible to create a function in MatLab that calls an EXE created in C#** so my scientific friends can go:

```
a = GetMeSomeData()
```

and populate the variable *a* with the response of the service? (I would, of course, format the data using my C# code so it'll fit the matrix model of MatLab.)

I've done some googling before I start working on this but most of the stuff I've found is about an old version of MatLab (2007) and it's said something about creating a COM object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily call functions in a .NET assembly. First you have to tell Matlab what assembly you are going to use:

```
NET.addAssembly("path//to//assembly.dll");
```

After that, you just call functions in your m-files:

```
foo = Namespace.Class.FunctionFoo(input1, input2);
bar = Namespace.Class.FunctionBar(input1, input2);
```

You can even have multiple outputs. A C# function like this:

```
public void MultipleOut(int in1, int in2, out int out1, out int out2)
{ ... }
```

can be called like this in Matlab:

```
[out1, out2] = Namespace.Class.MultipleOut(in1, in2);
```

Comment: Hi, I did all of you told but I got this error from matlab "The class dllForMatlab.Class has no property or method named 'MultipleOut'."  Do you have an idea about it?

Comment: @sigara Matlab says it can't find the method. Do you have one? Is it public? Are you calling it with the right inputs/outputs?

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a look at this: [Using .NET libraries in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/using-net-libraries-in-matlab.html).

There's plenty of documentation there.

Start with [`NET.addAssembly`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/net.addassembly.html)`('path-to-dll)`, and then it seems you can just use the classes normally as you would in .NET.

You might also want to take a look at [Using Arrays with .NET Applications](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-arrays-with-net-applications.html).

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question directly, you can use the [`system`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/system.html) command or [`!`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_env/creating-opening-changing-and-deleting-files-and-folders.html#f0-38522) in MATLAB to execute an external process. Once it returns you can read and parse the output from your MATLAB function. Wrap that all up in a MATLAB .m file and you have what you describe in the question.

Of course, you could just access the web service directly from MATLAB with [`createClassFromWsdl`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/createclassfromwsdl.html). And as others point out, [`NET.addAssembly`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/net.addassembly.html) allows you to import and use your .net assembly directly from MATLAB, which may be cleaner than parsing text file output.

Comment: I'm going to need to restructure and clean up the data before the actual use. Being much more savvy on C#, than MatLab, I think it's safest to rely on that. My scientist friends are less savvy on both .NET and MatLab than my computer mouse so there won't be any help coming from that direction. Good point, though.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I lean towards the most direct solution - to code all the connectivity in MatLab. I'm not that good at MatLab (haven't touched that thing since 2006 for my diploma work) but it might be fun to pick it up again. Am I correct assuming that there are ways to consume any service even if it doesn't offer WSDL file? As far I've seen SOAP is the only alernative. Correct?

Comment: Yes you can consume SOAP from Matlab. I don't know if that's the only option. How is the websearvice exposed. WSDL is easiest.

Comment: I think it's going to be WSDL. Thanks!

Comment: I decided to try your suggestion, skip the C# totally and build the solution based on MatLab only. Would you mind taking a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532299/how-to-design-a-soap-call-in-matlab), where I get stuck? Thanks!

Comment: You're reading about SOAP in that question. Use the function found in my answer for WSDL. There's a link too. Anyway, perhaps you should be asking the person whose answer you accepted rather than me!  ;-)

Comment: Hehe, good point. But I have a very good motivation to why I did that. Both your answers are very informative and helpful. So why him? Well, you've got **200 times** more reputation than him. So I figured that for you it doesn't matter but for him, it's a nice kick-up motivating to further contributions. But if you're trying to chase Skeet, I'll gladly put some bounty on one of your future replies to my upcoming questions (I'll be doing some integrations between our stuff and MatLab projects at the Polytechnic in Stockholm this spring, so there'll be issues to ask, hehe).

Comment: Yeah, I'm just kidding. You've got 3 decent answers here. You can only pick one. And I was interested to learn about the .net assembly interop. Pretty cool stuff.

Comment: I've made it work for unprotected calls but I seem getting nowhere when I need to call services that require authorization. I get errors that *@id* hasn't been specified in a SQL statement and I have no idea how to specify it. Suggestions? MatLab can't have such a limitation, right?!

Comment: I don't know. Sounds like it depends on details that we haven't got. Like the authorization details.

Comment: Sorry, still a bit confused on the subject. I'm looking through all the info in MatLab but I can't find anything that describes how to provide the authorization. It just says that `GetBlah(obj, auth)`. The WSDL at the server has a tag *auth* with to subtags but I'm not crear on the syntax of how to specify them. I asked about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848470/how-to-enter-credentials-authorize-object-in-a-web-service-call) but got no replies so I'm starting to worry that perhaps it's not doable... What information need I to provide in order for others to be able to help me?

Comment: Did you ask Mathworks? The one time I put in a support request I received excellent and attentive support.

Comment: I haven't thought of that, assuming SO to be the mother of all source of knowledge, haha. I put my question there now. Let's hope it's not a dead-end. I asked a friend to put a bounty on my question, too, but that has to wait until tomorrow, apparently.