# How to design a SOAP call in MatLab

Tags: matlab, soap

I'm not clear at all on how to call a web service from MatLab. I'm trying to apply [this guide](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_external/accessing-web-services-using-matlab-soap-functions.html) but I don't understand several parts. For instance this.

- Where is is specified that it's GET or POST?
- What is *namespace*?
- How am I supposed to provide the WSDL file I have?

I'm quite lost so any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use WSDL, you are working from the wrong documentation. You linked to a guide about SOAP.

To learn about WSDL, read this: [Access Web Services That Use WSDL Documents](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/accessing-web-services-that-use-wsdl-documents.html). When you use MATLAB's `createClassFromWsdl`, you don't need to worry about the SOAP implementation. The generated MATLAB class takes care of that.

Comment: Amazing! It actually worked on the first attempt. I think I'll deliver the whole shabang using MatLab, without mixing in .NET. I have to admit MatLab had become much nicer and pleasant to work with since my days at the university. (Also, now you'll get your green check so you can keep on chasing Skeety, haha.)

Comment: Yes, it's pretty slick isn't it. MATLAB is excellent in so many regards. Just a shame about the pricing.

Comment: Yupp, I just noticed that they even started to request payment from students. And it's not just a few bucks. We're talking almost a hundred smackaroos. For a poor student, it's a lot of dineros. Not to mention the commercial licenses. That's a string.

Comment: I only have licences to support my clients. Who I tell to use Python instead!

Comment: Broken link.  Maybe https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/access-services-that-use-wsdl-documents.html ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the web service definition list (WSDL), you can go like this:

```
wsdl = createClassFromWsdl('http://server.domain/NameOfMethod.asmx?WSDL')
calls = methods(NameOfMethod)
response = HelloWorld(NameOfMethod, "Konrad")
```

See [this info](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/createclassfromwsdl.html). It's very easy to follow and straight-forward to grasp. I'm surprised myself.