# Error using C# / .NET library in Matlab

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

Good afternoon,

I'm hoping to interface some C# code with Matlab, and following the advice posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489849/is-it-possible-to-use-net-application-in-matlab) I'm starting simple with the following function:

```
namespace MatLabLibrary
{
    public class MatLab
    {
            public int sum(int first, int second)
            {
                  return first + second;
            }
    }
}
```

I save this as a DLL file, and then try to load it into Matlab with the following command:

```
asm = NET.addAssembly('C:\Users\name\Documents\MATLAB\dllTests\MatLabLibrary.dll');
```

and then try to call it as follows:

```
foo = MatLabLibrary.MatLab.sum(5,7);
```

I then get the following error

```
Undefined variable "MatLabLibrary" or class"MatLabLibrary.MatLab.sum".
```

If I print the value of the variable asm, I see the following:

```
NET.Assembly handle
Package: NET

Properties for class NET.Assembly:

AssemblyHandle
Classes
Structures
Enums
GenericTypes
Interfaces
Delegates
```

All of the fields are empty except for AssemblyHandle, which has a bunch of other fields that I can post if it is helpful.  Any thoughts on getting this ironed out would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to define your method as static to call it like this. So, "public static int sum(..."

Comment: @Evk tried that as well and get the same error.

Comment: To create an instance of your class in MATLAB, try something like:

    instance = MatLabLibrary.MatLab;   
    result = instance.sum(1, 2);

Comment: Should work according to that: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/access-a-simple-net-class.html. Ensure that you recompiled and replaced that dll. Maybe also make class itself static (but doubt this has any effect). Also, check if it works with System.DateTime class, as provided in examples by link above.

Comment: @Jacob I actually found a small typo in my original C# source - so fixing that and making the method static worked.  Going to ask my coworker to rebuild the DLL without making the method static just to verify it was a wonky typo on our side.  I'll post back the result for future readers just in case.  D'oh!

Comment: Okay, so my colleague updated the code to make a non-static method and I got the following error: The class MatLabLibrary.MatLabLibrary  has no Constant property or Static method named 'sum,' so it seems that yes, properties and methods need to be static.  Thanks for the help all.

Comment: The Matlab run time library only contains definition for matlab functions.  User code must be defined using a DllImport statement.

Comment: My mistake, that was a static call. Here's how to use an instance if you're still curious: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-a-net-object.html